# JAX-WS wants soap webservice response in particular format

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have implemented JAX soap webservice using spring. My method signature is

String validate(String argu)

For this I have service:

```
@WebService
public class ValidationWS
{

    TestValidation TestValidation;
    @Resource(name = "wsContext")
    WebServiceContext wsContext;

    /**
     * @return the testValidation
     */
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public TestValidation getTestValidation()
    {
        return testValidation;
    }

    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public void setTestValidation(final TestValidation testValidation)
    {
        this.testValidation = testValidation;
    }


    @WebMethod(operationName = "validateToken")
    public String validateToken(final String argu)
    {
        return testValidation.validate(argu);
    }

}
```

Everything is fine and getting following response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:validateResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.validation.test.com/">
         <return><validate><returnCode>InvalidToken</returnCode></validate></return>
      </ns2:validateResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

But I want response in below format mean to say my result is not under tag . Want response in below format:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns1:validateResponse xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.validation.test.com/">
         <validateResult xsi:type="xsd:String"><validate><returnCode>InvalidToken</returnCode></validate></validateResult>
      </ns1:validateResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Can you please let me know how can achieve this. As tried other way but not able to find solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer and did following change in the service:

```
@WebService
public class ValidationWS

{

TestValidation TestValidation;
@Resource(name = "wsContext")
WebServiceContext wsContext;

/**
 * @return the testValidation
 */
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public TestValidation getTestValidation()
{
    return testValidation;
}

@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public void setTestValidation(final TestValidation testValidation)
{
    this.testValidation = testValidation;
}

@WebResult(name = "TokenResult", targetNamespace = "http://token.test.com/", partName = "TokenResult")
@WebMethod(operationName = "validateToken")
public String validateToken(@WebParam(partName = "token", name = "token", targetNamespace = "http://token.test.com/")final String token)
{
    return testValidation.validate(argu);
}

}
```